# Resource <Number of resource ID> type 0x12 is not valid

Tags: java, android

Activity starts. Theese code frames passed well.

```
    // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
    // one for newly discovered devices
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0x7f060008);
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0x7f06000b);

    // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
    ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
```

Constructor passed well. Application crashed with error message:

```
10-12 17:07:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 17:07:59.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11557): android.content.res.Resources    $NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060008 type #0x12 is not valid
```

XML resource file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/device_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/xaccel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/paired_devices" >
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_scan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scanning" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/other_available" >
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/new_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="122dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.70" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

R.java is as follows:

```
package medynets.dmytro;

public final class R {
public static final class attr {
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int BluCar=0x7f060000;
    public static final int button_connect=0x7f060002;
    public static final int button_forward=0x7f060004;
    public static final int button_light=0x7f060003;
    public static final int button_reverse=0x7f060005;
    public static final int button_scan=0x7f060009;
    public static final int device_list=0x7f060007;
    public static final int new_devices=0x7f06000b;
    public static final int paired_devices=0x7f060008;
    public static final int textView1=0x7f060001;
    public static final int title_new_devices=0x7f06000a;
    public static final int xaccel=0x7f060006;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_blucar=0x7f030000;
    public static final int device_list=0x7f030001;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int app_name=0x7f04000e;
    public static final int bt_not_enabled_leaving=0x7f04000f;
    public static final int connect=0x7f040003;
    public static final int connected=0x7f040010;
    public static final int device_list_activity=0x7f04000d;
    public static final int devices=0x7f040012;
    public static final int disconnected=0x7f040011;
    public static final int forward=0x7f040005;
    public static final int ledOFF=0x7f04000b;
    public static final int ledON=0x7f04000a;
    public static final int light=0x7f040004;
    public static final int no_bt_device=0x7f04000c;
    public static final int none_found=0x7f040008;
    public static final int none_paired=0x7f040009;
    public static final int other_available=0x7f040007;
    public static final int paired_devices=0x7f040001;
    public static final int reverse=0x7f040006;
    public static final int scanning=0x7f040002;
    public static final int select_device=0x7f040000;
}
public static final class style {
    /** 
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

     */
    public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f050000;
    /**  Application theme. 
 All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
     */
    public static final int AppTheme=0x7f050001;
}
}
```

Please, help me. I have no idea. I will send any additional information on your request.

Comment: www.google.com + "type #0x12 is not valid" request

Comment: I doubt that this is the correct way of doing it as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. I added to source code:

```
Import android.R;
```

Then all links to R I changed to:

```
medynets.dmytro.R
```

Then code:

```
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,medynets.dmytro.R.layout.paired_devices);
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, medynets.dmytro.R.layout.new_devices);
```

I changed to:

```
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
```

Afterall application runs.

Comment: Yea, Android can change the memory references in the R file which is why you should never link them directly.